# typescript Web page development in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, three.js

I am trying to set up a project in Visual Studio 2017 that does what I am already doing in Visual Studio Code.

I have is a typescript Web page which uses THREE for WebGL so it is client intensive.   It needs to interface to a custom Web server running on localhost.   For Visual Studio Code I open the Web site, set up the source maps and I can set breakpoints in the typescript for the Chrome debugger inside Visual Studio Code.  A true IDE for typescript.

Here is what I have tried with Visual Studio 2017:

1-  Open a Web Site.   This is the same Web site that works in Visual Studio Code.   I cannot get the typescript to build.

2-  Create node.js typescript project.  Typescript builds but I cannot connect to any Web server and see my code.  I can only start up server.ts.  In theory I can build a Web server in node.js but I need to connect to my custom Web server.

3-  Set up a C# ASP project.   I can build typescript and set breakpoints but the breakpoints are not hit.

The third option was recommended as a way to get typescript to compile but it builds C# DLL’s and doesn’t seem logical.  I don’t remember whether I could attach to my custom Web server or not.  This was in response to the disappearance of the typescript Web page from the templates on VS2017.

Visual Studio Code has its advantages but it is brittle.  The breakpoints stop working sometimes and now I can’t get source maps to work.  In theory this should all work perfectly on Visual Studio 2017 right?